# RPM to be installed only on AWS ec2 redhat instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat, rpm, rpm-spec

I am trying to build an RPM which should only be installable only on AWS EC2 redhat instances and not on other environments.

I currently have no clue on how to limit it only to aws ec2 instance. Can someone help share thoughts on how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to find a file that is unique to that install and then add it to your `Requires` tag, e.g. `/etc/redhat-release-aws` or something. If that file didn't exist, it wouldn't install, but something like `yum` wouldn't be able to help you out either, it wouldn't, for example, say "This RPM requires AWS." It would just tell the user a file is missing.

If it's not a specific file, you *could* write a script and put it into the `%pre` section. Not having AWS, I'll make believe there's a command you can run called `is_aws`; you can replace that with something like "`grep -iq aws /etc/os-release`"; anything that would return true/false.

```
if is_aws; then
  true # do nothing
else
  echo "This RPM requires AWS!" 1>&2
  false
fi
```

I'm 90% sure that the `%pre` scriptlet is run in "`set -e`" mode where the `false` will cause install to fail. `STDOUT` is ignored in non-verbose mode, so you need to write to `STDERR`.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat's RPM does not permit dependencies on environmental properties.  Other RPM variants do.  It may be possible to achieve something similar with a YUM plugin.

In general, such dependencies are not a good idea because it prevents creation of system images on staging systems which do not have the exact properties of the target system (e.g., the staging system might not be an AWS system).